# How to obtain four fusion batteries?

Tags: fallout-tactics

I have just completed the mission in `Peoria` and have found three fusion batteries and spared all the villagers. The village elder thanked me and said he'd give me a fourth fusion battery but there are still only three in my inventory and the elder refuses to speak anymore. Does it still count as if I still had four fusion batteries (thus earning a promotion), the last one beeing "invisible" to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer and it's two-fold:

1. The elder did NOT give me a battery. The three in my inventory are what I had. Getting the end brief from the general indicated that I executed the mission satisfactory i.e. obtained three batteries.
2. By dropping my three batteries on the ground and then talking to the elder, I ended the conversation with one battery plus three on the ground. The end briefing recognized this and the general lauded me fo it.

In conclusion: drop your batteries on the ground before talking to the elder.